# Strange behaviour of the If() statement

Tags: vb.net

today I stumbled upon a strange behaviour of the VB.net If() statement. Maybe you can explain why it is working like it does, or maybe you can confirm that it is a bug.

So, I have a SQL database with a table "TestTable" with an int column "NullableColumn" that can contain NULL. I'd like to read out the content of this column.

So I declare a variable of type `Nullable(Of Integer)` for that matter, open a `SqlClient.SqlDataReader` for "SELECT NullableColumn FROM TestTable" and use the following code to get the content of this column:

```
Dim content as Nullable(Of Integer)

...

Using reader as SqlClient.SqlDataReader = ...
  content = If(reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("NullableColumn")), Nothing, reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("NullableColumn")))
End Using
```

But after that my variable `content` has the value 0, not `Nothing` as I would have expected.

When debugging everything looks alright, so

- `reader.GetOrdinal("NullableColumn")` delivers the correct ordinal position of this column (which is 0)
- `reader.IsDBNull(0)` and `reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("NullableColumn"))` deliver `True`, since the content of this column indeed is NULL
- `If(1=2, Nothing, "Not Nothing")` delivers the String "Not Nothing"
- `If(1=1, Nothing, "Not Nothing")` delivers `Nothing`
- `reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("NullableColumn"))` throws an error, since NULL can't be converted to `Integer`

So, why does my variable has the value 0?

Comment: Have you used a normal If - then - elese statement? Does it work?

Comment: Out of interest do you have `Option Strict` turned on? If not you should

Comment: Yes, I tried a normal `If ... Then ... Else ...` statemant, and this worked.  Switching on `Option Strict` didn't change a thing.

Comment: Yeah, I had the same issue in my code. Problem with `Nothing` in VB.NET. I guess just avoid short constructs like that and use `If Then`, it's easier to debug anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In VB Nothing is not the same as null.  The If operator must determine the type of its result based on the arguments passed to it.  Nothing, of course, has no type so the only type that the If operator can return in your code is Int32.  If the IsDBNull method returns true, then the If operator returns Nothing cast as Int32.  In VB, Nothing returns the default value for a type.  For an Int32, the default value is 0.

From MSDN on the Nothing keyword:

```
Nothing represents the default value of a data type. The default value depends 
on whether the variable is of a value type or of a reference type.

For non-nullable value types, Nothing in Visual Basic differs from null in C#. 
In Visual Basic, if you set a variable of a non-nullable value type to Nothing, 
the variable is set to the default value for its declared type. In C#, if you 
assign a variable of a non-nullable value type to null, a compile-time error 
occurs.
```

I think just a regular If would work best:

```
If Not reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("NullableColumn")) Then
    content = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("NullableColumn"))
End If
```

Or to keep it shorter

```
If Not reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("NullableColumn")) Then content = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("NullableColumn"))
```

Answer (score 1):

> But after that my variable `content` has the value `0`, not `Nothing` as I would have expected.

How do you check the `content` value?

First of all, you should start with `content.HasValue` property. It should be `False` for your case of `Nothing` and `True` when correct value was fetched from database.

You should also get `InvalidOperationException` while accessing `content.Value` when it hasn't got value.

Comment: If I move my mouse over a variable in debugging mode I see the content of this variable. A nullable object type shows `Nothing`, if it has no value and the actual value, if it does.
If I use a normal `If ... Then ... Else ...` statement, the Intellisense shows `Nothing`, if I use the `If(...)` statemant, the Intellisense shows 0.

Answer (score 1):

Chris has given the explanation but I dislike the style of assignment he’s chosen because it splits assignment from variable declaration.

By contrast, I recommend initialising variables upon declaration. In this case it’s admittedly slightly convoluted since you need cast either operator of `If` to the correct type first.

```
Dim content = If(reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("NullableColumn")),
                DirectCast(Nothing, Integer?),
                reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("NullableColumn")))
```

Actually you can also use the slightly shorter `New Integer?()` instead of the `DirectCast`.

Of course now `content` is declared inside the `Using` block – this might not be what you want but you *should try* to make the declaration as local as possible.

Furthermore, this code is complex and will probably be reused. I suggest creating a separate (extension) method to convert database NULL values to nullables:

```
<Extension> _
Public Shared Function GetNullable(Of T)(SqlClient.SqlDataReader this, String fieldName) As T?
    Dim i = this.GetOrdinal(fieldName)
    Return If(this.IsDBNull(i), New T?(), this.GetFieldValue(Of T)(i))
End Function
```

Now you can use it as follows:

```
Dim content = reader.GetNullable(Of Integer)("NullableColumn")
```